# Do blocking creatures heal back to full between phases?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am new to MTG and this has been bothering me. Say I use any spell on my 1st main phase to deal 1 damage to my opponenent's 2/5 creature.

If I attack him during the combat phase of the same turn with a 4/3 creature and he blocks me using that 2/5 I previously did 1 damage to, will my 4/3 creature kill it, or his creature would have "healed" up between phases?

Comment: Phases? No. Turns? Yes. Creatures heal at the end of every turn (regardless of whose turn it is).

Comment: @Corsika I would avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: I'd rather avoid a drawn out comment thread here. If you want to discuss that position, I [made a room for us to do so](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25703/comment-discussion-with-rainbolt).

Comment: In this situation, I would recommend attacking first, and then if your opponent blocks, you can use your spell in the second main to finish off the blocker. Otherwise, if your opponent doesn't block, you may have just wasted the spell.

Answer (score 21):

It will be destroyed. All damage done to the creature in most cases stays until the very end of the turn (cleanup step).

> **119.6.** Damage marked on a creature remains until the cleanup step, even if that permanent stops being a creature. If the total damage marked on a creature is greater than or equal to its toughness, that creature has been dealt lethal damage and is destroyed as a state-based action (see rule 704). All damage marked on a permanent is removed when it regenerates (see rule 701.12, “Regenerate”) and during the cleanup step (see rule 514.2).